# c graphics in linux

Tags: c

hi 
can any one tell me how to make graphics program in c in Linux.
what header file i should use in gcc.I'm quite novice to Linux
thanx in advance

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. You may want to start by reading about something like http://www.libsdl.org.

Comment: He probably wants something like gtk+

Answer (score 3):

Googling for *linux graphics library c* gave [this site](http://www.thefreecountry.com/sourcecode/graphics.shtml) with tons of libraries for all kinds of languages under all kinds of operating systems. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

[libSDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is one good library.

Answer (score 1):

The [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net) library is pretty easy to use and covers a lot more than graphics.